# Pstricks not working after update MacTeX 2015

Tags: pstricks

After an update on MacTeX, my code stopped working. I am not sure what gives. My preference is to use PDFLaTeX (I am using the shell-escape option) but XeLaTeX is also not working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks} tried this too as well and worked for something else.

\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=10cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.2,-0.06)(4.1,0.57) 
\psBinomialN[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,showpoints=true,markZeros]{36}{0.5}
\psaxes[Dy=0.2,dy=0.2\psyunit]{->}(0,0)(-4,0)(4,0.5)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

I have tried using \begin{postscript}...\end{postscript} and that also have failed and that was something that has worked in the past as well. Can someone tell me what I am missing in order to get PDFLateX to work? For completeness, what about XeLaTeX?

There are some other things that stopped working, but I will start here.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is missing `usepackage{pst-func}`. However, this works with up-to-date TL 2015 and `xelatex`, `pdflatex -shell-escape` and loading package `auto-pst-pdf` and also with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\begin{document}
    \psset{yunit=10cm}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-4.2,-0.06)(4.1,0.57) 
    \psBinomialN[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,
       showpoints,markZeros]{36}{0.5}
    \psaxes[Dy=0.2,dy=0.2\psyunit]{->}(0,0)(-4,0)(4,0.5)
    \end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

If it doesn't work for you then post the filelist (at the end of your logfile)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert. It works now for this example. However, I encounter new problems with a larger file. I will try to make a MWE out of it.